# Has anybody successfully embedded a bokeh server in a google colab notebook?

Tags: python, bokeh, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a copy of [bokeh/notebook_embed.ipynb](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb) in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#recent=true).  All cells execute fine but `show(modify_doc)` produces no output.  What value should I pass as `notebook_url`?

I have looked at the console in chrome devtools and it's pretty clear that default values don't apply to this environment (I see some localhost:8080 all over the place).

Answer (score 0):

Covered in the docs here:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=JGnotb1n73Yk

The crucial bit is to initialize the output iframe before use.

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
output_notebook()
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that colab help entry. Unfortunately, it only applies to "static" bokeh charts, not the more complicated embedded server case. My question is specifically about embedding a bokeh server.

Comment: Almost two years after asking this, I managed [a kludge](https://github.com/jburgy/blog/blob/master/notebooks/Fake%20Bokeh%20Server%20Colab.ipynb).

It doesn't actually embed a bokeh server as shown [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/main/examples/howto/server_embed/notebook_embed.ipynb) but rather piggy-backs off the running `ipython` server using [Jupyter Comms](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=YOd4khppTskD)